# Aproximating with step functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have to find a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ of step functions , given a function $f\in L^1$, such that $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)-g_n(x)|dx \rightarrow 0$.

I tried using the obvious $$ g_n(x) = \sum_{i=n^2}^{n^2} f(i) \chi_[\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}]$$

If I consider it in $E_r$ , where $r<f(x)≤r+1$, the error is proportional to $r$ and inversely proportional to $n$, but when I do the integral, it doesn't converge as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Any ideas how I could solve it?

Comment: $r < f(x) \leq r+1$ does not give you an interval. Do you know that integrable functions cane be approximated by continuous functions?

Comment: Your functions $g_n$ do not give  you the approximation unless you make some continuity assumptions on $f$.

Comment: Yes, I know it isn't an interval, it was just to calculate the error in each of those sets, which make up all $R$. Also, my problem is to aproximate by step functions , not continuous , and I know that I can do it, but I don't know which function will satisfy the conditions.

Comment: No, continuity is not a hypothesis. What function should I use then?

Comment: You cannot do this directly starting with an arbitrary $L^{1}$ function $f$. You have to use some other known results. One result says there exists a continuous function $g$ with compact support such that $\int |f-g|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? How could I construct the function?

Comment: Thar requires quite a bit of work. It is proved using Lusin's Theorem Reference: Rudin's RCA.

Comment: you must use the regularity of the Lebesgue measure and the fact that any bounded open set in $\Bbb R $ is a finite and disjoint union of open intervals to approximate any simple function by an step function